# Envoy Proxy with Docker for grpc-web. Using ssl results in ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID on browser

Tags: docker, ssl, lets-encrypt, envoyproxy

I am trying to configure my envoy proxy to allow for save requests from my angular application to my application server using grpc. I have a letsencrypt certificate loaded, but the requests fail and chrome prints a: ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID when trying to connect. I have an apache2 running serving my web application. The envoy proxy on docker and the web application are running on the same machine.

my envoy.yaml:

```
admin:
  access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9901 }

static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 17887 }
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        config:
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          stream_idle_timeout: 0s
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["myactualdomain.com"]
              routes:
              - match: { prefix: "/" }
                route:
                  cluster: greeter_service
                  max_grpc_timeout: 0s
              cors:
                allow_origin_string_match:
                - prefix: "*"
                allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                max_age: "1728000"
                expose_headers: grpc-status,grpc-message
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.grpc_web
          - name: envoy.cors
          - name: envoy.router
    tls_context:
        common_tls_context:
            alpn_protocols: "h2"
            tls_certificates:
            - certificate_chain: { filename: "/etc/fullchain.pem" }
              private_key: { filename: "/etc/privkey.pem" }
  clusters:
  - name: greeter_service
    connect_timeout: 1.00s
    type: logical_dns
    http2_protocol_options: {}
    lb_policy: round_robin
    hosts: [{ socket_address: { address: localhost, port_value: 17888 }}]
```

I was thinking i might be because I am not using the traditional https port.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it working. First of all I added a new subdomain for the envoy proxy and created a new pair of certificates. Also don't do this: domains: ["myactualdomain.com"] but rather ["*"] as this leads to a CORS violation. If you only connect with grpc-web and the envoy don't use ssl as they run on the same machine anyway. If you wan't to do that though, you might want to take a look at that: https://medium.com/@farcaller/how-to-configure-https-backends-in-envoy-b446727b2eb3, I didn't try it though.